# My render layers are gone (Video Sequence Editor)

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, video, render-layers

I tried to render my Video by using "Render Animation", but it just gave me an error that said "All render layers are disabled". I tried to enable them, but it appears that there are no render layers.

[image]

Am I missing something or are all my render layers gone? Is there an easy way to restore them?

I am working on version 2.79, but I did switch briefly to the 2.8 version, which might've caused this problem.

Comment: what does this have to do with the VSE?

Comment: It's generally not recommended to open a file 2.79 file in 2.8 and then go back to 2.79. I would guess this is the problem.